# Reference for Taylor's Theorem $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, taylor-expansion, book-recommendation, jet-bundles

I am looking for a reference/ book recommendation that in detail exhibits the theory behind [the general Taylor theorem using jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)#One-dimensional_case)
for functions $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$

\begin{align} 
f(x) = f(x_0) &+ Df(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0) + \frac 12 D^2f(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)^{\otimes 2} + \ldots \\
&+ \frac {1}{k!}D^kf(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)^{\otimes k} + R_{k+1}(x)
\end{align}

Things that should be covered:

- Tensor products of Hilbert spaces
- Fréchet derivatives
- Jets
- The isomorphism $\underbrace{L(V,L(V,\ldots L(V,W))\ldots)}_{n \text{ times}} \cong L(V^{\otimes n}, W)$
- Some concrete example with $m,n\ge 2$, $k>2$

Comment: Is that isomorphism right?

Comment: Anyway, look for Foundations of Modern Analysis by Jean Dieudonné.

Comment: @WillM. The index neither mentions Fréchet derivates, nor Tensors let alone Jets. I don't think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Dieudonné, like most people, just call it derivative and polynomials. Not "Frechet derivative" and "k-jets." Cartan "Differential Calculus" also have both materials, though Cartan calls them "finite developments" rather than "k-jets."

Answer (score 0):

The best reference that I know of is [Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications Volume I: Fixed-Point Theorems by Eberhard Zeidler](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387909141). Quick note, B-space means Banach space.  Then, on page 148 and 149:

[image: Taylor's theorem 1]
[image: Taylor's theorem 2]